# Fiji not recognizing built in macro functions

Tags: javascript, macros, imagej

I'm trying to make a macro using the javascript editor in Fiji (version 2.0.0-rc-30/1.49u) running on OSX 10.6.8, and I'm having trouble using the built in macro functions. The meat of my code works just fine, but I'd like it to cycle through all the files in a specific folder, so my macro starts off with:

```
inputdir = "/Users/myusername/picture folder/"    
list = getFileList(inputdir);
```

And then I have a for loop that runs through each of the files, or at least that's the idea. When I run it I get the following error:

```
"ReferenceError: "getFileList" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#3) in <Unknown source> at line number 3"
```

I get similar errors for most of the built-in macro functions (getDirectory, selectWindow, setThreshold).

I'll be the first to admit I'm a novice at javascript, so I'm sure it's something bone-headed, but I've reinstalled imageJ and Fiji, and updated them both to no avail.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also trying to incorporate the Image Calculator into my macro. I'm using code from the macro recorder, which looks like this: ic = new ImageCalculator(); imp2 = ic.run("min", imp, imp1); where imp and imp1 are open images, and I get an error saying "Can't find method ij.plugin.ImageCalculator.run(string,sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Undefined,string).  This part lies within a function if that's important.

Comment: You are mixing up Javascript and the ImageJ macro language here: `getFileList()` is a macro function, so make sure you select *Language > IJ1 Macro* in the script editor to get it work. On the contrary, the code you show in the comment is Javascript.

Comment: Also have a look at the [Scripting toolbox](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_toolbox#Opening.2C_processing.2C_and_saving_a_sequence_of_files_in_a_folder) for help how to loop over a list of files in a folder.

Comment: One last helpful resource is the Templates menu of the Script Editor. If there are snippets on the Scripting toolbox page that are especially helpful, let us know and we can add them to the Templates menu. Right now there is Templates > IJ1 Macro > Process Folder for looping over files in a directory using a macro—but nothing similar for JavaScript yet IIRC.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes sense.  Thank you so much for your help Jan and ctrueden.

Answer (score 2):

First of all macros do have access to *some* of the Java functions.

He missed a semicolon in his code:

```
inputdir = "/Users/myusername/picture folder/"  // Forgot semicolon here. 
list = getFileList(inputdir);
```

So the code actually does work, just watch your syntax :). I suggest coding in Notepad++ or some compiler to make sure there aren't syntax errors.

There is something built into Fiji that makes this a lot easier called the multiple image processor.

The tutorial [here](http://fiji.sc/How_to_apply_a_common_operation_to_a_complete_directory) will show you exactly how to access it and apply your macro to a directory.

Alternatively you can program it in yourself which they also detail like so:

```
input = "/home/fiji/input/";
output = "/home/fiji/images/";

list = getFileList(input);
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    action(input, output, list[i]);
}
```

Of course you really should make this as a plugin if you want it to have access to all features of Java.

Also ImageJ(FIJI) supports [the following languages](http://fiji.sc/Scripting) if you weren't aware:

- BeanShell.
- Groovy.
- ImageJ Macro.
- Java.
- JavaScript.
- Lisp (Clojure)
- Python (Jython)
- Ruby (JRuby)